# Skip history.state and go to previosu page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-history

I'm working on something another developer left, so I'm not completely sure how all of these function works. So, I'm using history.pushState to save some values, to be able to prefetch some of my data. For example, I'm saving pageNumber and productCount in my state, so I can use it later on.

So, on the view I'm using this on, a history.state-log in the console could look like this:

```
init: null
pageNumber: 3
productCount: 150
```

So for each browser back button click it removes a piece of this state. So first back button click changes the example to

```
init: null
pageNumber: 3
```

Next click:

```
init: null
```

Next click:

```
null
```

So, in order to go back to the previous page, I need to click my button four times, because I manually remove each piece of state, and then finally I go back. I'm wondering if there's a way to remove all history.state on the browser back button click and instantly go to the previous page? Otherwise I'm thinking I could rewrite all of this code to use localStorage instead, but I'm also thinking that there has to be a reason that the History API is being used.

Comment: Sounds like an _abuse_ of the history API to me, at least so far. localStorage sounds way more appropriate, if all you have to do is store some values, but not in any way actually connected to the user’s browsing path across the site ...

Answer (score 1):

> So, in order to go back to the previous page, I need to click my button four times...

It sounds like the problem isn't going back, it's `pushState`. You're creating multiple history entries by calling `pushState` several times, so that's why you have to hit [Back] so many times.

It sounds like at least some of those should be `replaceState`, not `pushState`, so they modify the current history entry rather than creating a new one.